# Jump out from array_walk

Tags: php

I wonder if there is a way to break the rest of walking through an array when you found your desired result:

```
array_walk($arr, function($value, $key)
{
    if($value == "test")
    {
        global $id;
        $id = $key;
        break; // I know that break doesn't work! that's just for example.
    }
});
```

The above example shows what I mean by jumping out from `array_walk`

Comment: To what end? You probably want `foreach` or an `Iterator`.

Comment: No, you can't.  In this case, why not just use a `foreach`?  I don't think `array_walk` is the right tool here.

Comment: yes, foreach is an alternative but I'm going to see if we can do that in the case of using `array_walk`, maybe `array_filter` or `array_map`

Comment: @revo: You can't "break out" of any of those.

Comment: @revo: Would `$id = array_search('test', $arr);` work here?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't want alternative methods, I know that there are so many ways for replacement. So we can't jump out from them? right.

Comment: @revo: What are asking?  You cannot "jump out" of (most) array methods.

Comment: @revo just edited my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853359/2112743) you could break the function with a cached exception:

```
try {
    array_walk($arr, function($value, $key)
    {
        if($value == "test")
        {
            global $id;
            $id = $key;
            throw new Exception;
        }
    });
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //
}

// Rest of your code
```

Although I would also recommend you to use a normal `break`able loop.

Good luck;

---

### EDIT

This may be a solution as well, more semantic. This doesn't break the closure, but run the conditional just once. Also gets rid of that nasty global.

```
$array = array(1,2,3,'test',5,6,7,8,9,10);
$stop = false;
$id = 0;
array_walk($array, function($value, $key) use ($stop, &$id){
    if (!$stop && $value == 'test') {
        $id = $key;
        $stop = true;
        echo $id;
    }
});
// This just echo 3;
```

Comment: Wow.  While that *is* a solution, I would never suggest it.  This is like using a jackhammer to hammer a picture frame hook.

Comment: Yes, you're definitely right is like using a gun to turn on a TV (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSLMo-lnsjg‎), but just for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: Haha. This is actually pretty funny :D In fairness, I think Axel has flagged this appropriately as not recommended. +1

Comment: If you *must* use `array_walk` (for whatever reason), then `$stop = TRUE;` is a decent solution.  `array_walk` might not be the right tool here though.

Comment: I'd suggest doing `if(!$stop && $value == 'test'){` instead.  That way it won't compare `$value` after it already found it.