# Skip iteration of array_map function if IF statement True

Tags: php, array-map

Is there a way to `break` or `continue` an iteration of the built-in method `array_map()` as you would in a normal for loop?

For example:

```
array_map(function (String s) {
    if (condition is met){
        continue;
    }
    return stuff;
}, $array_to_map);
```

Comment: But wouldn't this defeat the whole purpose?

Comment: You should probably use `array_filter`. What is your input and output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jump out from array\_walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503625/jump-out-from-array-walk)

Comment: @ggorlen input is class object of strings output is array of strings

Comment: @d1596 It's helpful if you include that in your post. I recommend showing a [mcve], otherwise, this looks like an [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) because it appears like you're attempting to use a tool in a way it wasn't meant to be used.

Comment: thats what i assumed, but I wanted to be sure. So a foreach statement would be better?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say because I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. `array_map` returns an array the same length as the original so you can't skip an item. i.e. Something needs to be returned on each iteration.

You could use `array_filter` to remove certain items.

Answer (score 4):

```
$results = array_map(function (String s) {
    if (condition is met){
        //do stuff 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return stuff;
}, $array_to_map);
```

`$results` will then contain a array with the orignal number of elements in it as the $array_to_map, only with array elements set to false when the condition failed

then do.

```
$array_with_elements_remove = array_filter($results, function($e){
    return $e; //when this value is false the element is removed.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate `continue` by simply returning the original value.

```
array_map(function($var){
  if(condition)
    return $var; //continue
  return $transformedValue;
}, $arr);
```

However there would be no way to actually `break` (except disgusting things like using a `StopIteration` exception class)

Comment: I don't think that 2nd [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) will happen.

Comment: Sure, but why post something like that? It's misleading. The manual on return states *"If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file."* - If you get a downvote, it wouldn't have been mine, just saying.

Comment: What bothers me is that you're bugged with the `return` statements not the fact that neither `condition` nor `$transformedValue` is actually declared.

Comment: "Bothers" you? huh?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner omitting the braces on a single-statement block is bad practice, but it's permissible.

Answer (score -1):

You can try sth like this:

```
$newArrayWithIds = [];

array_map(function (int $id) use ($newArrayWithIds): void {
   if($id === 0) {
     return;
   }
   $newArrayWithIds[] = $id; 
}, $yourArrayWithIds);
```