# How to use array_in with multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

I have a array in below format

```
Array ([abc] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [abc_id] => 10 [status] => true ) [1] =>
Array ( [abc_id] => 11 [status] => true ) [2] => Array ( [abc_id] => 12 [status] => true ) ) 
[pqr] => Array ( ) [xyz] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [xyz_id] => 8 [status] => false )
[1] => Array ( [xyz_id] => 9 [status] => false ) ) [mno] => Array ( ) [def] => Array ( ) [unit_id] => 1)
```

And I want to check if there is a status = false word in the entire array.
I tried using array_in but couldn't succeed. Can anyone give me some proper solution for the above issue? Is there any other way to check if the array includes false anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) which will go through all levels of a multidimensional array - BUT only the leaf nodes.  Although that is fine as that is what you want.

This code has a found flag and a simple function which checks the label and the value for the values your after and sets the flag to be true if they both match...

```
$found = false;
array_walk_recursive($aray, function ($item, $key) use (&$found) {
    if ( $key === "status" && $item == false) {
        $found = true;
    }
});
echo $found;
```

Comment: Hi sir @Nigel Ren your code is working,only had to replace '==' with '=== ' in if condition.I have made some changes according to my requirement ie. i have to return a value depending on if condition when condition is true i have send success and if false the failed. so i used else part also.but when i use else part it works as follows hi : hello :1 hi :1.

Comment: Here is code with changes :                                                                           
 $found = false;
  array_walk_recursive($output, function ($item, $key) use (&$found) {
    if ( $key === "status" && $item == "false") {
        $found = true;
  echo "hello :".$found;
  
    }
 else
 {
  echo "hi :".$found;
  
 }

Comment: Yes done.Sir is it possible to stop if condition once it gets 1st false value.I mean if there are 3 false values in whole array than I want to give message  as failed once it matches with 1st false .and if there is no false in whole array  than success

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a way of stopping on 1st match unless you throw an exception. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853113/break-array-walk-from-anonymous-function shows how if you want to have a look.

Comment: OK. Thanks ill go through the link.